# Can't see my mobile sd card in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb-drive

I am unable to see the SD card of my mobile phone when I plug it into my PC via USB, but when I plug in my USB pen drive it will detect it automatically. Is there any way to show the SD card of my Android mobile phone when I plug it in via USB?

Comment: Do you remove the sd card from your phone or do you connect the phone directly to your pc? In the latter case, you might need to enable a "storage device mode" or similar on your phone

Comment: You should choose the _storage_ mode on your phone (refer to its docs) to make SD card seen as the external drive.

Comment: Did you install the mtpfs and mtp-tools packages?  Some tablets seem to need them (mtp=media transfer protocol).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what John_West said, depending on the type and software on your phone, you might have to "allow" your computer to see the card (input on your phone may be required after plugging it in). How this is called in detail varies on the manufacturer.